# Rearranging the word "of"

Tags: sentence-construction

I believe this sentence is grammatically correct:

> Let's have a civil dialogue, to the extent that we're capable of.

Can I replace **of** to form a sentence like this?

> Let's have a civil dialogue, to the extent that of we're capable.

The reason for doing this is that I'm not a fan of having "of" at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence

> Let's have a civil dialogue, to the extent that we're capable of.

is grammatical, although the inversion to place of at the end is a little unusual. However, the suggested alternate form:

> Let's have a civil dialogue, to the extent that of we're capable.

is **not** grammatically correct. In this construction "to the extent that of" is not a possible form. If it is desired to recast the original to avoid placing "of" at the end (although no rule requires doing so) one could write:

> - Let's have a civil dialogue, to the extent of which we're capable.
> - Let's have a civil dialogue, to the extent that we can manage.
> - Let's have a civil dialogue, insofar as we can.
> - Let's have a civil dialogue, to the best of our capacity.

These all carry prwtty much the same meaning, and other forms are possible. This choice is a matter of style, not grammar.

Comment: Why not "Let's have a civil dialogue, to the extent we're capable."?

Comment: @Ron I think that is basically an elision of my first suggestion.  It is slightly ambiguous, as it is not clear whether we are  limited by our capacity for civility, or for discussion, but in context should be clear. I don't happen to like that form, but there is nothing wrong with it.